# Encoding numbers to a single number

Tags: algorithm, encoding, numbers, integer, transformation

I have a problem with numbers and their representation.

I have a set of natural numbers with the maximal possible value of 1 000 000, call it NUM. Take 1-50 numbers from set NUM, where the same number can be included multiple times, call it IN. Transform set IN to a single number(OUT) with these conditions:

1. OUT will uniquely identify set IN.
2. it will be possible to use comparison of two OUT numbers (<,>,<=,>=), depends entirely on the time of creation of OUT (only one OUT created at one time)

(3. preferable) It will be possible to transform OUT to the original set IN.

---

Example:

`NUM={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,......,1000000}`

`IN1={2,4,6}, creation time 1`

`IN2={1,3,8}, creation time 2`

`IN3={4,4,4}, creation time 3`

### ---------------------------------------------

`OUT1=function(IN1,time 1)`

`OUT2=function(IN2,time 2)`

`OUT3=function(IN3,time 3)`

1. OUT1 != OUT2 != OUT3
2. OUT1 < OUT2 < OUT3
3. IN1=reverse_function(OUT1)

---

Is there a way to find this `function()` or `reverse_function()`???

Comment: There are several ways. You could for instance let *n* be represented by the *n*:th prime number, and use multiplication. Suppose you want to store `2`, `4` and `5`, you would use `3*7*11 = 231`. To get back to `2`, `4` and `5`, you simply factorize `231`. (Works also for repetition of numbers.)

Comment: `OUT will uniquely identify set IN` will require _huge_ values of out, depending on the cardinality of `IN` (and the number of possible values for `time of creation`). With `OUT` unique, re/inverse should not be a problem.

Comment: What exactly do you call "a single number". There is no native data type big enough to pack 50 numbers in range one to one million (i.e. 300 digits ~ 997 bits).

Comment: How do you represent a "creation time" ?

Comment: @aioobe just confirming your solution will not preserve sequence or order of numbers in set, i understand thats not a requirement in the question.. vs MrSmith42 anwers will preserve?

Answer (score 7):

There are several methods.
A very common way is to map every different number to a prime number and than encode how often this umber occurred in the exponent.

It is called [Gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering)

you could even get rid of the mapping from the numbers to primes if each number can only occur once. Than you could store the number itself in the exponent of a prime (a different prime for each number)
e.g. is you would like to store {123,47,2} you could do it
like this:

```
result=(2^123)*(3^47)*(5^2)
```

Than you can reverse this by making a prime factorization and look at the exponents.

Comment: Does it really only work with integers?  And could you explain in more detail the procedure for recovering a sequence from a Gödel number using factorization?

Comment: and one more note: the author of the question in the example gives a vector containing a million integers. How huge would the Gödel number encode such a sequence...

Answer (score 3):

You basically **can't** do the part where OUT uniquely identifies IN, if IN is a set of numbers with 1-50 members where each member could be a number from 1 to 1,000,000 and repetition is allowed.

Obviously if the set only contains one number, then there are only a million possible sets, and therefore your function only needs to return a million possible values.

If the sets always contain two numbers, and they might be the same number, then there are 500,000,500,000 (500 billion) possible combinations, so your function would need to return 500 billion possible values.

If the sets contain *either one or two* values, then obviously there are 500 billion + 1 million possible return values.

If we add sets with three numbers, the possible return values move into the quadrillions. By the time we include sets with twenty numbers, the range of values needed to uniquely identify each set has reached 40 googols (a 4 with 101 zeroes after it). This value would require over 42 bytes to store in memory (I doubt you are working in a language that allows 340-bit integers).

This is not a workable idea. You would be far better off joining text representations of the numbers with pipe characters or similar. While there are still just as many possible values, you would not be allocating enough space to store every single one - just the ones you use.

"1|2|3" uniquely identifies the set {1,2,3}, is reversible, is hashable, and is also human readable. It also takes up 6 bytes of memory and takes a very short time to construct. Any algorithm that generates a unique 340-bit integer to represent all you possible values is going to be complicated, unwieldy and generate values that you can't do anything with.

Comment: The string representation is not particularly compact. For a uniform distribution of the 50 input numbers, the average length of a number is 5.88 digits; adding the pipe, you get a total of 344 bytes, or 2752 bits. A pure binary representation requires 997 bits. By concatenating the binary representations of the numbers it only takes 1000 bits and direct access is possible.

Comment: Well yes, the fact is that turning a set into a single value probably doesn't really need to be done. A variable-length structure of some kind that simply holds the numbers themselves in binary format is just as good and *is* the set.

Really this is a problem that needs more context. It might be a case of asking what kind of knot is the strongest, while not mentioning that you're building a wall by tying bricks together with string.

Putting that aside, it would be good to know how many numbers will usually be in the set, how many need to be stored at any time, and so on.